# Unable to verify Web Service signature while deploy the application in WAS-8.5.5 server

Tags: java, jax-ws

The server code is able to verify signature while deploy the application in Tomcat server. But the same code while deploy in WAS-8.5.5 server, I'm getting response as "signature is invalid".

I'm using below code to sign the soap message in client side

```
    private static SOAPMessage signSOAPMessage(ByteArrayOutputStream out ){
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = null;
    MessageFactory messageFactory = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream signOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try{
        messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
        String keystoreType = "JKS";
        String keystoreFile = "test.jks";
        String keystorePass = "test123";
        String privateKeyAlias = "testExample"
        String privateKeyPass = "test123";
        String certificateAlias = "testExample"; 
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
        ks.load(fis, keystorePass.toCharArray());
        PrivateKey  privateKey = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPass.toCharArray());
        javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setAttribute("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", Boolean.TRUE);
        javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        db.setErrorHandler(new org.apache.xml.security.utils.IgnoreAllErrorHandler());
        String str = new String(out.toByteArray());
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(is);
        Element headerElement = null;
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","Header");
        if(nodes.getLength() == 0){
            headerElement = doc.createElementNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","Header");
            nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","Envelope");
            if(nodes != null){
                Element envelopeElement = (Element)nodes.item(0);
                headerElement.setPrefix(envelopeElement.getPrefix());
                envelopeElement.appendChild(headerElement);
            }
        }else{
            headerElement = (Element)nodes.item(0);
        }
        XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(doc, "", XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA);
        headerElement.appendChild(sig.getElement());
        Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
        transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_ENVELOPED_SIGNATURE);
        transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_C14N_WITH_COMMENTS);
        sig.addDocument("", transforms, org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(certificateAlias);
        sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
        sig.addKeyInfo(cert.getPublicKey());
        sig.sign(privateKey);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        XMLUtils.outputDOMc14nWithComments(doc, baos);
        SOAPPart soapPart =     soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        InputStream inputSOAP_REQUEST = new ByteArrayInputStream(new String(baos.toByteArray()).getBytes("UTF-8")); 
        StreamSource prepMsg = new StreamSource(inputSOAP_REQUEST);
        soapPart.setContent(prepMsg);
        soapMessage.writeTo(signOut);
        baos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return soapMessage;
}
```

In server side to verify the signature I used below code

```
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    boolean validSignature = false;
    logger.info("Server executing SOAP Handler");
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Boolean outBoundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    logger.info("OutBound Property : "+outBoundProperty);
    if (!outBoundProperty) {
        try {
            SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
            soapMsg.writeTo(out);
            logger.info("Input Message : "+new String(out.toByteArray())); 
            InputStream inputSOAP_REQUEST = new ByteArrayInputStream(new String(out.toByteArray()).getBytes("UTF-8")); 
            org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
            javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            dbf.setAttribute("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", Boolean.TRUE);
            javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            db.setErrorHandler(new org.apache.xml.security.utils.IgnoreAllErrorHandler());
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(inputSOAP_REQUEST);
            Element sigElement = null;
            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants.SignatureSpecNS,"Signature");
            if(nodes.getLength() != 0){
                logger.info("Found " + nodes.getLength() + " Signature  elements.");
                sigElement = (Element)nodes.item(0);
                XMLSignature signature = new XMLSignature(sigElement,"");
                KeyInfo ki = signature.getKeyInfo();
                if(ki != null){
                   //if(ki.containsX509Data())
                       //logger.info("Could find a X509Data element in the  KeyInfo");
                   X509Certificate cert = signature.getKeyInfo().getX509Certificate();
                   if(cert != null){
                       logger.info("The XML signature is Valid : " + signature.checkSignatureValue(cert));
                       if(signature.checkSignatureValue(cert)){
                           validSignature = true;
                       }else{
                           generateSoapErrorMessage(soapMsg,"Invalid Signature");
                       }
                   }else{
                       logger.info("Did not find a Certificate");
                       PublicKey pk = signature.getKeyInfo().getPublicKey();
                       if(pk != null){
                           logger.info("The XML signature is Valid : " + signature.checkSignatureValue(pk));
                           if(signature.checkSignatureValue(pk)){
                               validSignature = true;
                           }else{
                               generateSoapErrorMessage(soapMsg,"Invalid Signature");
                           }
                       }else{
                           logger.error("Did not find a public key, so I can't check the signature");
                           generateSoapErrorMessage(soapMsg,"Didn't find certificate to verify the signature");
                       }
                   }
                }else{
                    generateSoapErrorMessage(soapMsg,"Didn't find any Certificate Information from Signature");
                }
             }else{
                 generateSoapErrorMessage(soapMsg,"Signature is missing in header");
             }
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }
    return validSignature;
}
```